# Angular Translate arrow function factory

Tags: angular, typescript, arrow-functions, ngx-translate

When I import `TranslateModule` using this code:

```js
TranslateModule.forRoot({
    loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
    }
})
```

where

```js
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}
```

everything works but if I use an arrow function:

```js
export const HttpLoaderFactory = (http: HttpClient) => new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
```

I got this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'HttpLoaderFactory' before initialization
    at Module.HttpLoaderFactory (app.component.ts:18:26)
    at Module.10617 (core-components.module.ts:18:29)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module.36747 (app.component.ts:18:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module.14431 (environment.ts:33:68)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at __webpack_exec__ (.*$:292:1)
    at .*$:292:1
    at Function.__webpack_require__.O (chunk loaded:23:1)
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this simply isn't supported in angular AOT.

Here is a [list of supported features](https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox#current-status) and [the issue mentioning it](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13702)

Comment: You are right, just found in Angular docs: "Factory functions must be exported, named functions. The AOT compiler does not support lambda expressions ("arrow functions") for factory functions.".